# Phonegap- Creating database in windows phone

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am new to `Phonegap`, developing a phonegap app, In which I want to use the local database but its not supporting the `webSQL` it only supports the local storage like

```
 window.localStorage.setItem("userId","123");
```

but I have a `JSON` list of Country, state, district and city which have to insert into database and populate in the `dropdown` as user selects the country name. How can i achieve this? Any suggestion would be appreciated. One more thing I achieved this in phonegap Android by webSQL Like

```
         var db;
            var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
            var maxSize = 65535;
            var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
        db.transaction(function (tx){
              tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STATE');
              tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STATE (Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,STATE_ID , STATE_NAME, COUNTRY_ID)');
              db.transaction(function(transaction) {transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO STATE(STATE_ID, STATE_NAME, COUNTRY_ID)VALUES (?,?,?)',[obj.S_id, obj.S_name, obj.country_id], nullHandler,errorHandler); },errorHandler,successCallBack)
              });

function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
        //alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);
        }

        function nullHandler(){};
        */
        // this is called when a successful transaction happens
        function successCallBack() {
        }
```

I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows phone` `IDE` for development.

Comment: you can try to install [this](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) plugin for using SQLite (WebSQL) for windows

Comment: is it applicable in windows7 phone aap?

Comment: as per the Doc it is compatible for WP8.

Comment: I need it in windows 7 phone